# Postgres' AT TIME ZONE not working in hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, timezone

Hibernate query

```
SELECT l.submissionDate from Lead l where date(TIMESTAMP l.submissionDate AT TIME ZONE :userOffset) = date(:submissionDate)
```

is throwing following issue

```
11:08:13.248 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - line 1:89: unexpected token: AT
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: AT
```

Comment: You've already asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems. First, it appears you are using HQL/JPQL queries with createQuery, and the `AT TIME ZONE` syntax is not supported in HQL, so you will have to use a native query instead. Meaning instead of the Java field names you will have to use the SQL native names for everything.

Second comparing two user-passed parameters in the where clause is pointless. I think that instead of:

```
date(TIMESTAMP '2018-03-31T21:45:00.000+0000' AT TIME ZONE :userOffset) = date(:submissionDate)
```

you meant:

```
date(l.submissionDate AT TIME ZONE :userOffset) = date(:submissionDate)
```

Now, adding the corrections, and assuming you followed common-sense naming conventions, your table and field names would translate to:

```
SELECT l.submission_date from lead l where date(l.submission_date AT TIME ZONE :userOffset) = :submissionDate
```

And your submissionDate parameter would have to be either a `java.sql.Date` or a `java.time.LocalDate`, so that you don't need the conversions.